# Observable subject event listener

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, observer-pattern

I was looking into Observables and their differences to EventEmitter and then stumbled upon Subjects ( which I can see Angulars EventEmitter is based off ).

It seems Observables are unicast vs Subjects that are multicast ( and then an EE is simply a subject that wraps .next in emit to give the correct interface ).

Observables seem easy enough to implement

```
class Observable {
    constructor(subscribe) {
        this._subscribe = subscribe;
    }

    subscribe(next, complete, error) {
        const observer = new Observer(next, complete, error);

        // return way to unsubscribe
        return this._subscribe(observer);
    }

}
```

Where `Observer` is just a wrapper that adds some try catches and monitors isComplete so it can clean up and stop observing.

For a Subject I came up with:

```
class Subject {
    subscribers = new Set();

    constructor() {
        this.observable = new Observable(observer => {
            this.observer = observer;
        });

        this.observable.subscribe((...args) => {
            this.subscribers.forEach(sub => sub(...args))
        });
    }

    subscribe(subscriber) {
        this.subscribers.add(subscriber);
    }

    emit(...args) {
        this.observer.next(...args);
    }
}
```

which sort of merges into an EventEmitter with it wrapping .next with emit - but capturing the `observe` argument of the Observable seems wrong - and like I have just hacked up a solution. What would be the better way to produce a Subject (multicast) from an Observable (unicast)?

I tried looking at RXJS but I can't see how it's `subscribers` array ever gets populated :/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you can have a better understanding by using the debugger as well. Open a StackBlitz RxJS project, create the simplest example(depending on what you're trying to understand) and then place some breakpoints. AFAIK, with StackBlitz you can debug the TypeScript files, which seems great.

---

Firstly, the `Subject` class [extends `Observable`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subject.ts#L17):

```js
export class Subject<T> extends Observable<T> implements SubscriptionLike { /* ... */ }
```

Now let's examine the `Observable` class.

It has the well-known [`pipe` method](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Observable.ts#L432-L434):

```js
pipe(...operations: OperatorFunction<any, any>[]): Observable<any> {
  return operations.length ? pipeFromArray(operations)(this) : this;
}
```

where `pipeFromArray` is defined [as follows](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/util/pipe.ts#L23):

```js
export function pipeFromArray<T, R>(fns: Array<UnaryFunction<T, R>>): UnaryFunction<T, R> {
  if (fns.length === 0) {
    return identity as UnaryFunction<any, any>;
  }

  if (fns.length === 1) {
    return fns[0];
  }

  return function piped(input: T): R {
    return fns.reduce((prev: any, fn: UnaryFunction<T, R>) => fn(prev), input as any);
  };
}
```

Before clarifying what's going on in the above snippet, it is important to know that **operators** are. An operator is a function which returns another function whose single argument is an `Observable<T>` and whose return type is an `Observable<R>`. Sometimes, `T` and `R` can be the same(e.g when using `filter()`, `debounceTime()`...).

For example, `map` is [defined like this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/map.ts#L44):

```js
export function map<T, R>(project: (value: T, index: number) => R, thisArg?: any): OperatorFunction<T, R> {
  return operate((source, subscriber) => {
    // The index of the value from the source. Used with projection.
    let index = 0;
    // Subscribe to the source, all errors and completions are sent along
    // to the consumer.
    source.subscribe(
      new OperatorSubscriber(subscriber, (value: T) => {
        // Call the projection function with the appropriate this context,
        // and send the resulting value to the consumer.
        subscriber.next(project.call(thisArg, value, index++));
      })
    );
  });
}

export function operate<T, R>(
  init: (liftedSource: Observable<T>, subscriber: Subscriber<R>) => (() => void) | void
): OperatorFunction<T, R> {
  return (source: Observable<T>) => {
    if (hasLift(source)) {
      return source.lift(function (this: Subscriber<R>, liftedSource: Observable<T>) {
        try {
          return init(liftedSource, this);
        } catch (err) {
          this.error(err);
        }
      });
    }
    throw new TypeError('Unable to lift unknown Observable type');
  };
}
```

So, `operate` will **return a function**. Notice its argument: `source: Observable<T>`. The return type is derived from `Subscriber<R>`.

[`Observable.lift`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Observable.ts#L66) just creates a new `Observable`. It's like creating nodes within a liked list.

```js
protected lift<R>(operator?: Operator<T, R>): Observable<R> {
  const observable = new Observable<R>();
  
  // it's important to keep track of the source !
  observable.source = this;
  observable.operator = operator;
  return observable;
}
```

So, an operator(like `map`) will return a function. What invokes that function is the `pipeFromArray` function:

```js
export function pipeFromArray<T, R>(fns: Array<UnaryFunction<T, R>>): UnaryFunction<T, R> {
  if (fns.length === 0) {
    return identity as UnaryFunction<any, any>;
  }

  if (fns.length === 1) {
    return fns[0];
  }

  return function piped(input: T): R {
    // here the functions returned by the operators are being called
    return fns.reduce((prev: any, fn: UnaryFunction<T, R>) => fn(prev), input as any);
  };
}
```

In the above snippet, `fn` is what the `operate` function returns:

```js
return (source: Observable<T>) => {
  if (hasLift(source)) { // has `lift` method
    return source.lift(function (this: Subscriber<R>, liftedSource: Observable<T>) {
      try {
        return init(liftedSource, this);
      } catch (err) {
        this.error(err);
      }
    });
  }
  throw new TypeError('Unable to lift unknown Observable type');
};
```

Maybe it would be better to see an example as well. I'd recommend trying this yourself with a debugger.

```js
const src$ = new Observable(subscriber => {subscriber.next(1), subscriber.complete()});
```

The `subscriber => {}` callback fn will be assigned to the [`Observable._subscribe`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Observable.ts#L34-L38) property.

```js
constructor(subscribe?: (this: Observable<T>, subscriber: Subscriber<T>) => TeardownLogic) {
  if (subscribe) {
    this._subscribe = subscribe;
  }
}
```

Next, let's try adding an operator:

```js
const src2$ = src$.pipe(map(num => num ** 2))
```

In this case, it will invoke this block from `pipeFromArray`:

```js
// `pipeFromArray`
if (fns.length === 1) {
  return fns[0];
}

// `Observable.pipe`
pipe(...operations: OperatorFunction<any, any>[]): Observable<any> {
  return operations.length ? pipeFromArray(operations)(this) : this;
}
```

So, the `Observable.pipe` will invoke `(source: Observable<T>) => { ... }`, where `source` is the `src$` `Observable`. By invoking that function(whose result is stored in `src2$`), it will also call the `Observable.lift` method.

```js
return source.lift(function (this: Subscriber<R>, liftedSource: Observable<T>) {
  try {
    return init(liftedSource, this);
  } catch (err) {
    this.error(err);
  }
});

/* ... */

protected lift<R>(operator?: Operator<T, R>): Observable<R> {
  const observable = new Observable<R>();
  observable.source = this;
  observable.operator = operator;
  return observable;
}
```

At this point, `src$` is an `Observable` instance, which has the `source` set to `src$` and the `operator` set to `function (this: Subscriber<R>, liftedSource: Observable<T>) ...`.

From my perspective, it's all about **linked lists**. When creating the `Observable` chain(by adding operators), the list is created from top to bottom.
When the **tail node** has its `subscribe` method called, **another list will be created**, this time from bottom to top. I like to call the first one the `Observable list` and the second one the `Subscribers list`.

```js
src2$.subscribe(console.log)
```

This is what happens when the [`subscribe`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Observable.ts#L206) method is called:

```js
const subscriber = isSubscriber(observerOrNext) ? observerOrNext : new SafeSubscriber(observerOrNext, error, complete);
  
  const { operator, source } = this;
  subscriber.add(
    operator
      ? operator.call(subscriber, source)
      : source || config.useDeprecatedSynchronousErrorHandling
      ? this._subscribe(subscriber)
      : this._trySubscribe(subscriber)
  );

  return subscriber;
```

In this case `src2$` has an `operator`, so it will call that. `operator` is defined as:

```js
function (this: Subscriber<R>, liftedSource: Observable<T>) {
  try {
    return init(liftedSource, this);
  } catch (err) {
    this.error(err);
  }
}
```

where `init` depends on the operator that is used. Once again, here is `map`'s `init`

```js
export function map<T, R>(project: (value: T, index: number) => R, thisArg?: any): OperatorFunction<T, R> {
  return operate( /* THIS IS `init()` */(source, subscriber) => {
    
    // The index of the value from the source. Used with projection.
    let index = 0;
    // Subscribe to the source, all errors and completions are sent along
    // to the consumer.
    source.subscribe(
      new OperatorSubscriber(subscriber, (value: T) => {
        // Call the projection function with the appropriate this context,
        // and send the resulting value to the consumer.
        subscriber.next(project.call(thisArg, value, index++));
      })
    );
  });
}
```

`source` is in fact `src$`. When `source.subscribe()` is called, it will end up calling the callback provided to `new Observable(subscriber => { ... })`. Calling `subscriber.next(1)` will call the `(value: T) => { ... }` from above, which will call `subscriber.next(project.call(thisArg, value, index++));`(`project` - the callback provided to `map`). Lastly, `subscriber.next` refers to `console.log`.

Coming back to `Subject`, this is what happens when the [`_subscribe`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subject.ts#L100) method is called:

```js
protected _subscribe(subscriber: Subscriber<T>): Subscription {
  this._throwIfClosed(); // if unsubscribed
  this._checkFinalizedStatuses(subscriber); // `error` or `complete` notifications
  return this._innerSubscribe(subscriber);
}

protected _innerSubscribe(subscriber: Subscriber<any>) {
  const { hasError, isStopped, observers } = this;
  return hasError || isStopped
    ? EMPTY_SUBSCRIPTION
    : (observers.push(subscriber), new Subscription(() => arrRemove(this.observers, subscriber)));
}
```

So, this is how `Subject's` list of subscribers are is populated. By returning `new Subscription(() => arrRemove(this.observers, subscriber))`, it ensures that then subscriber unsubscribes(due to `complete`/`error` notifications or simply `subscriber.unsubscribe()`), the *inactive* subscriber will be removed from the `Subject`'s list.