# Do RxJS operators use .subscribe() under the hood?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am wondering how RxJS operators such as .map() 'listen' to the incoming observable stream. Does .map() and other RxJS operators subscribe to the stream under the hood in order to get access to the observable values?

If I am understanding it correctly, each operator subscribes to the input observable, which gives it access to the stream of values then returns an observable of the transformed values to the next operator? Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: I think this might be helpful https://netbasal.com/creating-custom-operators-in-rxjs-32f052d69457

Comment: Might have something to do with [lazy functions](https://jrsinclair.com/articles/2018/how-to-deal-with-dirty-side-effects-in-your-pure-functional-javascript/#lazyfunctions) and [effect functors](https://jrsinclair.com/articles/2018/how-to-deal-with-dirty-side-effects-in-your-pure-functional-javascript/#theeffectfunctor). This article is also a part of [the Angular guide for non-local side effects in applications](https://angular.io/guide/strict-mode#non-local-side-effects-in-applications).

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is **yes**. I've elaborated a bit on it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64120874/9632621)

From my perspective, the magic of RxJS is achieved with **linked lists**.

Imagine you have something like this:

```js
const src$ = new Observable(subscriber => subscriber.next(1))

const src2$ = src$.pipe(
  map(/* ... */),
  filter(/* ... */),
  takeWhile(/* ... */)
)
```

An operator is a function which returns another function whose single argument is an `Observable<T>` and whose return type is an `Observable<R>`. Sometimes, `T` and `R` can be the same(e.g when using `filter()`, `debounceTime()`...).

`Observable.pipe` is the important part here. This method is what creates an *observable linked list*. The process is detailed in the linked answer, but, briefly, this is what you'd roughly get:

```js
S1 // new Observable(...)  - the HEAD node
|
S2 // map() - another observable, whose `.source` is `S1`
|
S3 // filter() - another observable, whose `.source` is `S2`
|
S4 // takeWhile() - another observable, whose `.source` is `S3`
```

When you subscribe(e.g `src2$.subscribe()`), a new chain will be created based on the existing one, this time it is the *subscribers chain*. Basically, a new subscriber will be created from `.subscribe(subscriber)`, which will subscribe to `takeWhile` observable, which will create a `takeWhile` subscriber, which will subscribe to `filter` observable, which will create a `filter` subscriber, which will subscribe to `map` observable and so on. Finally, the `subscriber` from callback from `new Observable(subscriber => subscriber.next(...))` will be, in this case, the `map` subscriber.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question. We first need to understand the behavior of Observables. **Observables** are cold by default. By cold it means that **unless a code-unit subscribes to it, it will not execute its functionality** Here is a quote from [angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/observables) website

> Observables are declarative—that is, you define a function for publishing values, but it is not executed until a consumer subscribes to it. The subscribed consumer then receives notifications until the function completes, or until they unsubscribe.

That is the reason we see the usage of rxjs **pipe** operator. **pipe operator** as the name suggests creates a **pipe-line** of cold rxjs operators that **augment** each previous operator. This declarative set of pipe-lined operators remain cold until / unless the final version of this declaration is **subscribed**.

So for example if you are making use of **map** rxjs operator, it would get triggered by the **subscribe** against the pipe-lined set of operators created. This pipe-line would get executed from left-to-right, thats first come first serve. Here is an example.

```
const req1 = of(1,2,3).pipe(map((x)={
return x * 2;
}));

req1.subscribe((x)=>{
console.log(x);
});
```