# How error and complete method from rxjs work?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

recently I've read about rxjs. This code is from the doc.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
 
const observable = new Observable(subscriber => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    subscriber.complete();
    subscriber.next(1);
  }, 1000);
});
 
observable.subscribe({
  next(x) { console.log('got value ' + x); },
  error(err) { console.error('something wrong occurred: ' + err); },
  complete() { console.log('done'); }
});
console.log('just after subscribe');
```

As it said that if either an Error or Complete notification is delivered, then nothing else can be delivered afterwards. How can it be done under the hood with pure js? Is there a way to alter the subscribe function and dynamically return when complete/error method executed?

Comment: When an Observable errors out or completes, it dies, so it can't emit anything else. What are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: Yes. I am rewriting an observable by pure js, so what I mean is implementing something to make it dies (as you said). I tried to early return when error/complete method executed, but as Andrei's answer, blocking the next method is what rxjs do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way RxJS works is very interesting. I shared my perspective on it in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64116710/observable-subject-event-listener/64120874#64120874). I tried to cover how `Observable.pipe`, `Observable.subscribe` and how `Subject.observers` work under the hood.

But the gist would be this(again, this is my perspective after spending some time reading the source code):

RxJS achieves its features through **linked lists**.

Basically, there are 2 linked lists. One is created with the help of `Observable.pipe()`, whose nodes are defined by the operators(e.g `filter`, `take`, `map`) and the other one is created on `Observable.subscribe()`. This is the `subscribers` list.

An operator is *accompanied* by a `Subscriber` instance. For example, the `map` operator has the `MapSubscriber`. The operators' subscribers were called exactly like this before RxJS 7, now it uses a very smart way to *inject* the [logic that defines the operator](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/map.ts#L44-L56).

> How can it be done under the hood with pure js

As mentioned before, each `Subscriber` has the `next()`, `error()`, `complete()` methods. For example, this is what happens [on `error()`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subscriber.ts#L77-L82):

```js
error(err?: any): void {
  if (!this.isStopped) {
    this.isStopped = true;
    this._error(err);
  }
}
```

`isStopped` makes sure that [no other `next` notifications](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subscriber.ts#L64) can be passed through:

```js
next(value?: T): void {
  if (!this.isStopped) {
    this._next(value!);
  }
}
```

Of course, this is not the only thing that happens when the `error` event occurs, RxJS also takes care of teardown logic, releasing resources.

Comment: Yeah. Thank you. I tried to early return when error/complete method executed, but haven't thought about blocking the next method by just an isStopped flag.